# How to Get Min Threshold value from a Stack using Imagej?

Tags: jython, imagej

I need to create a Jython script to calculate a minimal threshold value from a
stack of images. It doesn't have to be on one image at a time but on the entire
stack histogram at once.
Is there any method to get this threshold from a stack processor?
This is how I tried to do it but it didn't work:

```
tempStackps = StackProcessor(tempStack)
minThresholdValue = tempStackps.getMinThreshold()
```

Thanks, jose.

Answer (score 0):

`getMinThreshold()` is a method of the [`ImageProcessor` class](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/process/ImageProcessor.html), returning the *current* lower threshold level of the image (if it has been set). What I guess you want is the *auto*-threshold based on the whole stack histogram. You can get it via [`IJ.setAutoThreshold`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/IJ.html):

```python
imp = IJ.getImage()
IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default dark stack")
minThresholdValue = imp.getProcessor().getMinThreshold()
IJ.log(IJ.d2s(minThresholdValue))
```

Hope that helps.